# Store UI column settings in DataBase

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I am developing a website which uses tables in UI, and our customer wants that the users  can **customize the columns** they want to see in UI for each table, and to **store this settings** inside the Database.

My question is: what is the cleanest way to support this feature into the Database, avoiding to have the data stored coupled to the UI?

Comment: You can create a stored-procedure and use `sp_executesql` with dynamic sql. The column- and table-names can be passed as parameter. These parameters can be loaded from a table where you store the table and the column, so one table+column is one record.

Comment: And how do I identify each UI table and column in Database? by name? And if in the future I decide to change the column name in UI? (for example, I put Email instead of Mail). That wouldn't be a very consistent solution...

Comment: There is no very consistent solution with your requirement. But you could store the `object_id` and the `column_id` instead, then you can change at least the names of the table and column. You SP needs to determine the names via `OBJECT_NAME(@tableID)` and `COL_NAME(@tableID, @columnID)`. You get the ID's with this sql query: `select *
from sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('TableName')`